# linq to sql insert statement not working

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following code:

```
        pillboxDataContext db = new pillboxDataContext();

        userAccount newUser = new userAccount();
        newUser.userName = "test123";
        newUser.userPhone = "1234567890";
        newUser.userEmail = "test@test.com";
        newUser.userPwd = "testpassword";
        newUser.userCreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        newUser.userAccountType = "basic";

        db.users.Add(newUser);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

userAccount is my object with properties (that match up with the user table).

I'm confused on the `db.users.Add(newUser);` line.  The .Add is stating: System.Data.LINQ.Table does not contain a definition for 'Add'.

The examples I was following seem to indicate that the .Add should be allowed.  I'm new at this so please any advice would be very helpful.

**UPDATE:**

I changed it to `db.users.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);` however, I'm still getting an error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Linq.Table.InsertOnSubmit(user)' has some invalid
>   arguments

**Fix!**

After looking at other code samples I figured out that I was assigning my data to the class (userAccount) rather than the table (user).

So I changed: `userAccount newUser = new userAccount();` to `user newUser = new user();`
Then everything worked like I expected.

Thanks for the info!

Comment: What is the type you have defined for `db.users`?

Comment: I don't think I did.  Where do I check that?

Comment: On your `pillboxDataContext`, what is the type for `users`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `Add` won't work - I suspect you want [`InsertOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx).

```
db.users.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon for answering my question.  I tried InsertOnSubmit however, I'm still getting an error.  See updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is:

```
db.users.InsertAllOnSubmit(newUser);
```

Jon suggested that your code should be:

```
db.users.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);
```

There is an enormous difference between the two.  An IDE is very helpful for this sort of thing...

Comment: Yup you are right.  That was a mistake on my part, however, I'm still getting an error.  Thank you for catching my mistake.